# Admob native ads showing same content

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I've put 4 unique native ads inside my application, but when I scroll through it and watch the Ads, I tend to notice that many times a couple of them show the exact same Ads LOL wouldnt it be better if the Ads always showed different, distinguished content? The Ads are not in Test Mode, they are the real deal.

Do I have to set the content up inside my Admob Account or is this done programmatically ? or am I not allowed to control it?

Comment: maybe you need add random ads targeting when request an ads [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/targeting) or
in admob native setting (when add new monetization) you can set Automatic refresh to 30sec, it mean new impression every 30 sec [Read doc here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3245199?ctx=tltp&hl=en#native)

Comment: yeah I've already set it to 30sec to refresh but still have this feeling...

Comment: try to use ads targeting then.